# Couples arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

9 couples are seated in a single row. How many ways can they be arranged so that the partners of each couple sit next to each other and, in addition, no person sits next to another person of the same gender?

Is the answer $9!\cdot 2$ ?

My thinking is that there are 9! ways of arranging the couples, and for each arrangement we can either let the Male be the one on the left and Female be on the left , or the other way round, so each of the 9! arrangements has 2 possible arrangements for a total of $9!\cdot 2$

Comment: That is correct.